# How to properly indent application in scheme-mode?

Tags: indentation, scheme

The `scheme-mode` indents application in this way:

```
(define (x)
  (x 1
     2))
```

But when the function to apply is the result of another application `scheme-mode` indents the code this way:

```
(define (f)
  ((f) 1
   2))
```

But I would like to indent this in the same way as the first.

```
(define (f)
  ((f) 1
       2))
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `scheme-mode` seems to get this behavior from `calculate-lisp-indent`. Coincidentally [I was looking at this exact behavior recently](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/issues/243#issuecomment-267156938). I'm not yet sure the best way to change it.